# Inherit only part of an enum

Tags: c#, enums

I have an enum in a parent class with several elements. I inherit that class in another. In the child class I want the enum to only have a part of the elements, not all of them. Is there a way I could implement this?

Comment: You can´t inherit an enum. You can *nest* your enum within another class however. Apart from this what you want tio do is not possible and probably even dagerous. Imagine someone calls this: `MyBaseClass b = new Derived(); b.TheEnum = ...`. How should the compiler infer the right type for the enum, when you provide the actual type of the *instance* at runtime?

Comment: Even if you could, it would achieve nothing, except some nicer IntelliSense. Remember that enums are just glorified integers -- `(MyBaseEnum) 17` is perfectly fine, even if there is no tag with value `17`. Simply leaving out values does not usually protect against the kind of things you want to protect against.

Comment: Yeah, I knew it couldn't be done but I wanted to ask anyway. I will think of another way not using enums.

Comment: @Megid: What particular task are you trying to solve? The question sounds like XY-problem.

Comment: You cannot inherit enums, but you could define the enum in the derived class so that it contains all values of base class enum. The logic in the derived class can affect enum fields in both derived and base class if that level of consistency is needed.

Comment: Something about this feels wrong.  Enums are basically constants.  If you're the one in charge of the enums and the logic is divided then I suggest dividing the enums into separate ones.  If you want only certain enums used then you should manage that logic internally of the class and not expose the enums as public parameter choices.  In other words, wrap the logic into methods that sets the enum.  Would you mind posting the code or pseudo?  I feel like there is a better solution you're overlooking.

Comment: It's not much to post because it's more of a question if I could theoretically. An enum in a parent class with a set of elements and the same enum in the child class with a subset of those elements. But I kinda get it it's not feasible, I didn't think so either. I will try to implement it in a different way.

Comment: If you can't think of a good example it may be because it isn't such a good idea after all :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't really, but you can create a struct with static private attributes, which won't be inherited to the derived class